# Доступ к сетевой папке из службы под пользователем SYSTEM

Tags: c++, сеть, windows-7, windows-service, users

Есть служба которая входит в систему под "NT AUTHORITY\System", по команде она должна создать папку по указанному пути. Конкретно с помощью вызова функции:

`int err = mk_dir("\\192.168.0.2\shared\123");`

Но при вызове этой функции я получаю ошибку Permission denied, однако если запустить службу под обычным пользователем, то все работает. Для папки выставлены права полного доступа для "Все" и "Гость".

Подскажите как настроить права доступа, чтобы служба под "NT AUTHORITY\System" могла иметь доступ к сетевым папкам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Для того чтобы разрешить анонимный доступ к сетевой папке, как в случае с пользователем "NT AUTHORITY\System", нужно изменить параметры локальной политики безопасности на машине с расшаренной папкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]